# Is there a way to combine contents of 2 txt files iterating for multiple lines using python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and I encountered this challenge
I have 2 txt files say test1.txt and test2.txt.

test1.txt contains the following:

```
111111111
222222222
333333333
444444444
555555555
```

while test2.txt contains:

```
aaaaaaa
bbbbbbb
ccccccc
ddddddd
```

Now I want to generate a new file that will look like this:

```
111111111
aaaaaaa
bbbbbbb
ccccccc
ddddddd
222222222
aaaaaaa
bbbbbbb
ccccccc
ddddddd
333333333
aaaaaaa
bbbbbbb
ccccccc
ddddddd
```

and so on....

I have tried several methods but it only combines the two files and that's it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. Show us the code you have made for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I am reading the lines of both files into two f1_lines and f2_lines respectively, then iterating over each line in test1.txt and printing that line along with all lines in test2.txt.

So, every time a line in test1.txt is encountered, that line plus all the lines in test2.txt will be printed.

```
with open('test1.txt','r') as f1, open('test2.txt','r') as f2:
    f1_lines=f1.readlines()
    f2_lines=f2.readlines()
    for line in f1_lines:
        print(line.strip())
        [print(line.strip()) for line in f2_lines]
```